# cp -H vs cp -L (What is a "command-line" symbolic link?)

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

My OS states the following in the man page of cp:

```
   -H     follow command-line symbolic links

   -L, --dereference
          always follow symbolic links
```

I am having difficulty figuring out what a "**command-line** symbolic link" is.

Comment: Have you already http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link?  It was the first hit when you Google for `symbolic link`.  Did you have some specific questions?  Did you not understand some of that?

Comment: @Zoredache: It seems to me that the OP knows what a symbolic link is, but doesn't understand the difference between the `-H` and `-L` switch.

Comment: @Zoredache Does your user agent not render emphasis in text? It's pretty clear that the OP is asking not what a symbolic link might be, but where lies the distinction between a **command-line** symbolic link, and the more usual sort. (There isn't one, but the lousy phrasing in the man page makes it seem as though there might be, and I don't blame the OP for being confused by it; I was as well, and had to work through the example described in my answer to understand what was actually going on.)

Comment: Yup, that's why I bolded command-line. A Google search didn't reveal anything about that type of symlink.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no such thing as a command-line symbolic link. The man page refers to links that occur on the command line, i.e., as arguments to the *cp* command.

Without the `-R` switch, the behavior of `cp -H` and `cp -L` is identical.

With the `-R` switch, `cp -H` only dereferences symbolic links that occur in the *cp* command itself, while `-L` also dereferences symbolic links inside the recursively copied directories.

The command

```
cp -R -H source/ dest/
```

will copy the directory *source* and all its contents inside the directory *dest*. If *source* is a symlink to a directory, cp will dereference the symlink, i.e., copy the directory *source* points to. However, if cp encounters any symlinks in *source*'s subdirectories, it will create symlinks in the destination folder.

The command

```
cp -R -L source/ dest/
```

behaves similarly. However, it will also dereference symlinks in *source*'s subdirectories, i.e., copy the files those symlinks point to.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it really well. The confusing part was about "command-line" symbolic links. I guess that means that if I did cp -HR folder mysymlink destinationFolder, then mysymlink would be followed, but not the symbolic links within destination folder. Basically, anything that appeared on the command-line after cp -H or cp -HR gets followed once (because they appear on the command-line), but any other linking after that does not.

Answer (score 1):

The `-H` option to `cp` modifies the behavior of `-R` (recursive copy) as follows:

If `-H` is *not* passed, and the source path given on the command line is a symbolic link to a directory, then the *link* will be copied to the destination path.

If `-H` *is* passed, and the source path &c., &c., then the link will be *dereferenced*, and the *referenced directory* recursively copied to the destination path.

That doesn't help much, I think; perhaps an example will clarify it better. (In `ls -pF` output, a trailing `/` indicates a directory, while a trailing `@` indicates a symbolic link.)

```
1  me@box tmp $ for dir in foo bar; do mkdir $dir; done
2  me@box tmp $ ls -pF
bar/ foo/
3  me@box tmp $ touch foo/file
4  me@box tmp $ ln -s foo baz
5  me@box tmp $ ls -pF
bar/ baz@ foo/
6  me@box tmp $ cp -R baz bar
7  me@box tmp $ ls -pF bar
baz@
8  me@box tmp $ unlink bar/baz
9  me@box tmp $ cp -HR baz bar
10 me@box tmp $ ls -pFR bar
bar:
baz/

bar/baz:
file
11 me@box tmp $
```

See how that works? At line 6, I issued `cp -R` without the `-H` option, and the *symbolic link* `baz` got copied into `bar/`. Then, at line 9, I issued `cp -HR`, and `cp` dereferenced `baz` and recursively copied its contents (i.e., the contents of `foo/`, as per line 4) into `bar/`.